# I am getting this error: System.MissingMethodException Message=Default constructor not found for type AbuseAlert.Views.Hotels

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I tap on a menu item, it is supposed to display a page containing several menu and sub-menu items, but it is giving the above error.

This is how I am trying to access the content page from my appshell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Services" Icon="icon_feed.png">

        <ShellContent Route="Hotels" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Hotels}" />
```

This is the Hotels.xaml.cs file I am trying to display in the Views Folder:

```
namespace AbuseAlert.Views

{
    public partial class Hotels : ContentPage

{

    private HotelsGroupViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (HotelsGroupViewModel)BindingContext; }
        set { BindingContext = value; }
    }

    private List<Hotels> ListHotel = new List<Hotels>();

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (ViewModel.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                ViewModel.LoadHotelsCommand.Execute(null);
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public Hotels(HotelsGroupViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;           
    }

   
}
}
```

This is the Hotels.xaml file:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Name="currentPage"
         x:Class="AbuseAlert.Views.Hotels">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid >
      
        <StackLayout x:Name="hotelStack" Padding="1,0,1,0" >
            <ListView
                x:Name="HotelsList"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadHotelsCommand}"
                >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        FontSize="Medium"
                                        Text="{Binding RoomName}"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />                                  
                            </StackLayout>                                   
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                           <Grid >
                               <Label
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            TextColor="Gray"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Image x:Name="ImgA" Source="{Binding StateIcon}"  Margin="0,0,5,0" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.RefreshItemsCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>                               
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

So, what do I do next to clear this error and get the content page to display?

This is HotelsGroupViewModel.cs.

```
using AbuseAlert.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AbuseAlert.ViewModels
{
    public class HotelsGroupViewModel : BaseViewModel2
    {
        private HotelViewModel _oldHotel;
    private ObservableCollection<HotelViewModel> items;
    public ObservableCollection<HotelViewModel> Items
    {
        get => items;

        set => SetProperty(ref items, value);
    }
  
    public Command LoadHotelsCommand { get; set; }
    public Command<HotelViewModel> RefreshItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public HotelsGroupViewModel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<HotelViewModel>();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<HotelViewModel>();
        LoadHotelsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommandAsync());
        RefreshItemsCommand = new Command<HotelViewModel>((item) => ExecuteRefreshItemsCommand(item));
    }
  
    public bool isExpanded = false;
    private void ExecuteRefreshItemsCommand(HotelViewModel item)
    {
        if (_oldHotel == item)
        {
            // click twice on the same item will hide it
            item.Expanded = !item.Expanded;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_oldHotel != null)
            {
                // hide previous selected item
                _oldHotel.Expanded = false;
            }
            // show selected item
            item.Expanded = true;
        }

        _oldHotel = item;
    }
    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommandAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;
            IsBusy = true;
            Items.Clear();
            List<Room> Hotel1rooms = new List<Room>() 
            {
                new Room("Record Audio", 1), new Room("Take a Photo", 1), new Room("Record Video", 1), new Room("Watch a LiveStream", 1), new Room("Broadcast a LiveStream", 1)
            };
            List<Room> Hotel2rooms = new List<Room>()
            {
                new Room("View RED Zone", 1), new Room("Manage RED Zone", 1)
            };
            List<Room> Hotel3rooms = new List<Room>()
            {
            };
            List<Room> Hotel4rooms = new List<Room>()
            {
            };
            List<Room> Hotel5rooms = new List<Room>()
            {
            };
            List<Room> Hotel6rooms = new List<Room>()
            {
                new Room("Support Tips", 1), new Room("Counselling Tips", 1), new Room("Chat", 1)
            };
            List<Room> Hotel7rooms = new List<Room>()
            {

            };

            List<Hotel> items = new List<Hotel>() 
            {
                new Hotel("Report Abuse", Hotel1rooms), new Hotel("RED Zone", Hotel2rooms), new Hotel("Location Inquiry", Hotel3rooms), new Hotel("Notify", Hotel4rooms), new Hotel("Voice2Text", Hotel5rooms), new Hotel("Support & Counselling", Hotel6rooms), new Hotel("Options", Hotel7rooms) 
            };

            if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var hotel in items)
                    Items.Add(new HotelViewModel(hotel));
            }
            else { IsEmpty = true; }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Default constructor = no parameters.

Comment: For announcement, when you load the `Hotels` in Shell via xaml, the `Hotels` constructure with parameters would throw errors. And If it is possible, could you provide the whole code for me to test the tap issue?

Comment: How do you want me to send the whole code to you? email?

Comment: You could upload on GitHub and provide me the link to download. I want to know what happened when you  tap on the ones.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is the gitHub link: https://github.com/aproko234/AbuseAlert

Comment: I have checked the sample you provided. It works well. Please check my screenshot when i tap the item, it would change the icon. https://imgur.com/jp2x8Ps

Comment: Ok. But, if you tap Report Abuse, it is supposed to expand and show about 5 new sub-items under Report Abuse (such as Take a Photo, Record Audio, Take a Video, etc.). It is not doing that.

Comment: It seems you want to open the `Report Abuse` contentpage to show the five Buttons(Record Audio, Take a Photo, Record Video...) when you tab Report Abuse. If yes, do the navigation to the page instead of expanding to show 5 sub itemsunder it when you tab Report Abuse.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is - `default constructor not found`

your page has a constructor with a parameter

```
public Hotels(HotelsGroupViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ViewModel = viewModel;           
}
```

but XAML pages require a **default** constructor, one that has no parameters

```
public Hotels()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```